# Mouse move events stop working after switching to other windows

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

`acceptsMouseMovedEvents` works fine, but when my apps window **is not in front**, mouse move event stops working. If my window is in front everything works

What should I do? I hope my apps can run in background.

Comment: Are you trying to get clicks from our side your applications? Becouse that’s not possible

Comment: i want the function like macOS app - Digital Color Meter , i think there is some way to do that. Because Digital Color Meter can keep working(RGB keep changing) when it is running in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get mouse position on demand by calling `NSEvent.mouseLocation`. This is how the digital color meter works (timer + mouselocation)

OBJ EXAMPLE

```
 _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                          repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
                                           NSPoint point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
                                           NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromPoint(point));
                                     }];
```

SWIFT:

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1,
                                 repeats: true,
                                 block: { timer in let point: NSPoint = NSEvent.mouseLocation
                                    print("(NSStringFromPoint\(point))")
})
```

Comment: timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
    var point: NSPoint = NSEvent.mouseLocation
    print("\(NSStringFromPoint(point))")
})